# keyboard shortcut to switch amongst windows on current desktop

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>cmd-`</kbd> switches amongst windows of the same program.  How do I switch amongst windows just on the current desktop?  I find it hard to use desktops without this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shortcut for that is ⌃F4. It can be changed in the keyboard preference pane.

[image]